# Search record using jsp-tags

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have a page containing a list of records. I need to have a search box in my list page where in, when the user type a key word and click the search button, the contents of the table should then be filtered depending on the keyword that the user typed in.

This is what I've done so far.

In my View, I have this:

```
         <form:find finderName="BySearchWord" id="ff_ph_com_domain_Accommodation" path="/accommodations">
            <field:input disableFormBinding="true" field="searchKeyword" id="f_ph_com_domain_Accommodation" max="255" required="true"/>
        </form:find>
```

I am using jsp-tags named find for this.

In my Controller, I have this method.

```
@RequestMapping(params = "find=BySearchWord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(@RequestParam("searchKeyword") String searchKeyword, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {
    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("accommodations", Accommodation.findAllAccommodationBySearchBox());
    } else {
        uiModel.addAttribute("accommodations", Accommodation.findAllAccommodationBySearchBox());
    }
    addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
    return "accommodations/list";
}
```

I honestly am not sure if it is right to put this here, but this is what I have on my domain so far.

```
public static List<Accommodation> findAllAccommodationBySearchBox() {
    return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT a FROM Accommodation a WHERE a.person.firstName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.middleName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.lastName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.room.roomNumber LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.pvId LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.startDate LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.endDate LIKE :searchKeyword", Accommodation.class).getResultList();
}


public static List<Accommodation> findAllAccommodationBySearchBox(String searchKeyword) {
    String jpaQuery = "SELECT a FROM Accommodation a WHERE a.person.firstName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.middleName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.lastName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.room.roomNumber LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.pvId LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.startDate LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.endDate LIKE :searchKeyword";
  if (searchKeyword == null || searchKeyword.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The search keyword is required");
  searchKeyword = searchKeyword.replace('*', '%');
  if (searchKeyword.charAt(0) != '%') {
    searchKeyword = "%" + searchKeyword;
  }
  if (searchKeyword.charAt(searchKeyword.length() - 1) != '%') {
    searchKeyword = searchKeyword + "%";
  }
    return entityManager().createQuery(jpaQuery, Accommodation.class).getResultList();
}
```

and this on another class:

```
public List<Accommodation> findAllAccommodationBySearchBox(String searchKeyword) {
    if (searchKeyword == null || searchKeyword.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The description argument is required");
    searchKeyword = searchKeyword.replace('*', '%');
    if (searchKeyword.charAt(0) != '%') {
        searchKeyword = "%" + searchKeyword;
    }
    if (searchKeyword.charAt(searchKeyword.length() - 1) != '%') {
        searchKeyword = searchKeyword + "%";
    }
    EntityManager em = Accommodation.entityManager();
    TypedQuery<Accommodation> q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Accommodation a WHERE a.person.firstName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.middleName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.lastName LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.room.roomNumber LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.person.pvId LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.startDate LIKE :searchKeyword OR a.endDate LIKE :searchKeyword", Accommodation.class);
    q.setParameter("searchKeyword", searchKeyword);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

I am following a tutorial I've found online but the structure of that is a bit different with what I have so I couldn't quite point out what I've not been doing. I'm really at a lost right now. I've been trying to figure this out for almost a day now.

P.S. I only got as far as being able to type something on the search box and having the page redirected after I clicked the search button but I only got an exception message saying "Query argument searchKeyword not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution."

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This whole code looks a little bit messy, but your first problem would be the `list(...)` method in your controller. It takes a lot of arguments but what it basically does is:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "find=BySearchWord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(@RequestParam("searchKeyword") String searchKeyword, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("accommodations", Accommodation.findAllAccommodationBySearchBox());

    addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
    return "accommodations/list";
}
```

because your if statement doesn't matter at all. So fix your if statement if you want it to do anything. You probably want to limit search result so pass the values to `findAllAccommodationBySearchBox()` and use them with `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResult()` methods.

Now, you call `findAllAccommodationBySearchBox()` method without any arguments (this shouldn't be possible at all using your query) which will always throw the exception as you don't provide the query with required parameters.

Your 'first' (you don't want to have two methods with same usage, same names, same arguments and even different code inside btw) `findAllAccommodationBySearchBox(String searchKeyword)` also doesn't add required parameter.

Comment: It is a lot messy, I admit. I modified my method and then added a parameter to findAllAccommodationBySearchBox() but it still returns the same exception. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You don't add parameter to the query in your 'first' method. Also, updated answer.

Comment: I removed my first method and the exception was gone. Instead, it just redirected to the list page but I don't think it run the query because the contents of the list are still the same.

Comment: Also, I added this **value="searchKeyword"** in my @RequestMapping